# Fragment containing multiple threads in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my `android` application I have one `activity` containing `ViewPager` for two `fragment`s. Inside both fragments I am communicating with server, which means there's NOT only UI thread. If I send a request to the server, a progress bar appears till a response comes back inside both fragments. The problem is that when the first fragment is visible to a user, the progress bar of the second fragment also apears.

I want to make it in a such way that the progress bar of one fragment should not disturb another fragment. However, the request should NOT be sent every time a user swithces `viewPager`.

How can this be done?